# How can i get RetailerID from sql table by giving RetailerName as input in logic apps

Tags: azure-logic-apps

How can I get RetailerID from SQL table by giving RetailerName as input in logic apps?

I have On-premises database with Retailer table. In that table, I have RetailerID and RetailerName. I give RetailerName as input for logic app(Example:priya) there I use get row action in logic app to get RetailerID for the RetailerName.

It doesn't get RetailerID for that RetailerName. but if I give 01 as id it shows Priya. I want to do this as a reverse. here is my table:

```
RetailerID|RetailerName
01        |Priya
02        |Darshini
```

How can I get that retailerID by giving RetailerName?which action should use?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the Get Row option because that will only take the row's primary key as a filter.  That's why it works when you use 01.

Instead, you can use **Get Rows** and set the filter on 'RetailerName' eq [myinputvariable].

Comment: i used Get Rows not Get Row. Please re-check my answer.Thank you

Comment: @priya "I use get row action in logic app".  ID is only an option on Get Row.  Can you edit you Question to clarify the situation.

Answer (score -1):

i used Get rows action in logic apps. there i selected advance options where i used RetailerName eq '@{body('Parse_JSON')?['ns0:Root']?['PurchaseOrder']?['RetailerName']}' to get RetailerName for that particular ID.